# Is it okay to be friends with a Tarot Reader?

Tags: halal-haram

I have a friend who’s a tarot reader but is it haram to still be friends with them in Islam?

Answer (score -1):

"I said: Messenger of Allah. I was till recently a pagan, but Allah has brought Islam to us; among us there are men who have recourse to Kahins (soothsayer). He said, Do not have recourse to them."

Muslim 537

He who visits a diviner ('Arraf) and asks him about anything, his prayers extending to forty nights will not be accepted.

Muslim 2230

"What it means by "his prayers extending to forty nights will not be accepted." Is explained by Imam Nawawi: As for "his prayers will not be accepted" means the person aren't getting rewards. However, the prayers he does are still considered to be able to invalidate his prayer obligations and he does not need to repeat his prayers" (Sharh Sahih Muslim 14:227)

Wallahu a'lam